# boost::posix_time' has not been declared

Tags: ubuntu, boost

When I try to compile the code with the lines bellow: (I'm using `boost 1.51`, with `gcc 4.6.3` in `UBuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits`)

```
 #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

 dotFile << "// " << boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() << std::endl;
```

I get this error:

```
sources/sctg/src/main.cc: In function 'void printDot(sctg::Configuration*, std::string, std::vector<sctg::Task*>*, std::vector<sctg::Event*>*)':
sources/sctg/src/main.cc:1029:31: error: 'boost::posix_time' has not been declared
```

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Try using quotes instead of brackets: `#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"`

Comment: Thanks, but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal test case works for me:

```
$ cat posix_time.cpp

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -Wall posix_time.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
2013-Jan-31 21:34:31
$
```

Try this and see if it works on your system. If it fails then I suspect that you have a problem with your boost installation (perhaps an empty header).

Comment: Thanks. Test case above works. I'm getting this error using "sccom" command from Modelsim.